# Using jQuery Address without jquery-migrate

Tags: jquery, jquery-address, jquery-migrate

I upgraded jQuery from 1.3.1 to 3.2.1. In the process, I used jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js. When I remove jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js, the page stops working properly until I also remove jquery.address-1.5.min.js. The only reason why I need jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js is because jquery.address-1.5.min.js uses deprecated code. Otherwise, I would be able to get rid of jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js because all of my code and plugins are now compatible with jQuery 3.2.1. I was reading https://github.com/asual/jquery-address/issues/159 and the reported issue is that "after upgrading to jQuery 1.9, jQuery Address stops working". This person reports that things work again when using jquery-migrate but with some warnings:

```
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js:29
JQMIGRATE: AJAX events should be attached to document: ajaxComplete jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js:29
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.live() is deprecated jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js:29
```

I am using jquery.address-1.5.min.js, which is the latest version available at http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/, and it is still not compatible with jQuery 3.2.1. It requires jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js in my case, because jquery.address-1.5.min.js contains deprecated jQuery code.

How can I use jQuery Address without jquery-migrate? I guess I would have to modify the original jquery.address-1.5.min.js and replace the legacy code with modern jQuery equivalents. Too bad that jquery.address-1.5.min.js does not offer a newer version. jQuery Address Plugin v1.5 is from 2012-08-17 16:32:52 -0700 (Fri, 17 Aug 2012). Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you answered your own question.

Comment: @Taplar I am looking for another alternative, but I guess that is the only thing I can do at this point.

Comment: If methods are removed that you depend upon, you either have to implement those methods yourself, or modify the logic that depends upon those methods to not depend upon them.  It can sux, but it's a pretty straight forward issue.

Comment: According to the project info on [github](https://github.com/asual/jquery-address) the latest version is 1.6, which adds *"Support for jQuery 1.9"*. I see you can access it also from [cdnjs.com](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.address).

Comment: @trincot Your comment was the solution. jQuery Address 1.6 does exist and it is compatible with jQuery 3.2.1! Why is it that they do not make version 1.6 available at http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/? I thought that was the official website of the plugin, but I am confused about what is the official website now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the project info on [github](https://github.com/asual/jquery-address) the latest version is 1.6, which adds *"Support for jQuery 1.9"*. So it should solve the problem you quoted from [issue 159](https://github.com/asual/jquery-address/issues/159) which was particularly related to compatibility problems with jQuery 1.9

I see you can access jQuery Address version 1.6 also from [cdnjs.com](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.address).

Answer (score 0):

The solution came from the comment trincot wrote to the question. I always thought that jQuery Address 1.5 was the latest version available because that is what they have at http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/. 1.5 appears as the only version available to download, and I cannot find version 1.6 anywhere. Why do they have version 1.6 only at https://github.com/asual/jquery-address and https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.address, but not in the official page of the plugin at http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/? Or maybe http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ is not the official page of the plugin?

I am going to mark this question as solved because by using jQuery Address 1.6, I do not need jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js anymore, so the question is already answered satisfactorily. However, I still think that jQuery 1.6 should have been available from http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ to avoid confusion, or remove that link and redirect to the official website of the plugin, in case http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ is not the official website.